# Does Python load a directory of parquet files in order while creating a Dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, sorting, pyspark, parquet

A large dataframe is sorted using OrderBy in Spark. The output generated is a directory with 200 parquet files containing the sorted data.

To combine all parquet into one single parquet file, I'm using python. When the directory is loaded into the dataframe using `pandas.read_parquet("Path_to/Directory_containing_200parquet_files")`, is the sort order maintained? or are the parquet files read in randomly?

Comment: Spark reads in parallel, so the order is not maintained.

Comment: @IslamElbanna the parquet files are being read using python to merge them to a single parquet

Comment: So Spark reads each file in order (usually a file will be loaded in one partition if it is small enough) but combining all files doesn't grantee the final order between files since each file could be loaded by a different executor

Comment: maybe you could partition by the same columns you're ordering by?